# Roles Claims are missing in Azure AD Access Token using App Authentication client library in .NET

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, azure-functions, access-token

I am trying to generate Azure AD access token (Application Only Token using Managed Identity Credentials) at backend that can be later used to invoke other APIs.

I created  App registration in Azure AD and exposed as an API.
I set application ID URI `api://CLIENT_ID`.
I created App roles and manifest looks like below.

```
    "accessTokenAcceptedVersion": 2,
    "appRoles": [
        {
            "allowedMemberTypes": [
                "Application"
            ],
            "description": "Search.Address",
            "displayName": "SearchAddress",
            "id": "82bc288b-b03b-4acb-a99b-f246d8ad1551",
            "isEnabled": true,
            "lang": null,
            "origin": "Application",
            "value": "Search.Address"
        }
    ],
```

I configured API permissions and granted admin consent for Application Permissions.

[image]

I created Azure Function App enabled System Managed Identity and tried below code to generate access token in HTTP Trigger Function.

**Code:**

```
using Azure.Identity;
using Azure.Core;

var credential = new ManagedIdentityCredential();
var accessTokenRequest = await credential.GetTokenAsync(new TokenRequestContext(scopes: new string[] { "api://bee96ec1-1acc-456c-847b-84f88870b1d9" + "/.default" }) { });
var accessToken = accessTokenRequest.Token;
```

I am successfully getting the Token but Roles are missing. Am i missing something in configuration?
**Why I cannot see scopes/Roles in Token?**

[image]

If I am generating access token using `client credentials` approach through Postman, **I can see Roles.** But I would like to avoid this approach as I no longer needs to store keys If I use Managed Identity approach.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It worked in my side so I can only try to share the differences I found and how I do in my side.

[image]

I noticed that the `aud` claim in my token is different from yours.

[image]

And we are using `DefaultAzureCredential`, so I followed [this section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/identity-readme?view=azure-dotnet#defaultazurecredential) and set environment variable for my app.

[image]

Comment: I am trying to use only Managed Identity Credentials  so that it does not requires to set System Variables. Have you tried with ```ManagedIdentityCredential``` ?

Comment: `ManagedIdentityCredential ` required an Azure subscription, but I don't have that. I mean if you can't do it with `ManagedIdentityCredential` right now, you may try to set the environment variable for your Azure function app for just a test, environment variable is used before managed identity

Comment: I dont have client secret and i should not create as per my requirement. So the reason making use of Managed Identity.

Comment: @PavanKumarGVVS Hi, I'm afraid that the issue is resulted from the limitation for managed identity. In my opinion, when we need to generate access token via Azure AD, we need to set the azure AD application id at least, that's the `aud` cliam represents in the token. But with managed identity, we only need to create a user assigned identity or a system consent identity. we don't set a specific Azure AD here. And I think that's why the token you generated had different behavior with mine in `aud` claim. Anyway,  this is my assumption...

Comment: Here's the section which related [target resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-managed-identity?tabs=portal%2Chttp#configure-target-resource). It looks like the managed identity is designed for visiting the Azure resources, but not the custom resource protected by Azure AD...